# Getting the UIViewController from an SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

From what I understand, the UIViewController manages interactions with the interface, such as transitions, while a View is just an object, a vessel for context. **Therefore, I am confused on how to get the UIViewController of an SKScene**

I am trying to implement *Google Mobile Ads* into my project:

```
interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: /* UIViewController */)
```

However, one of the arguments requires an UIViewController object. I have looked at some other different questions, but most were a bit outdated and in Objective-c. **Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to get the UIViewController of an SKScene**

This is the method where I am initializing the interstitial:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "code")
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)

        if interstitial.isReady {
        //    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: /* UIViewController */)
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }

        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.17, green:0.24, blue:0.31, alpha:1.0)
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view controller is:

> `self.view?.window?.rootViewController`

**Example:**

```
        let isReady = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady          
        guard let controller = self.view?.window?.rootViewController as? GameViewController else {return}

        if isReady {
            print("ADMOB: started")
            GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: controller)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the VC on your skscene and set it to self on your View Controller. Something like this:

SKScene

```
  var viewController: myViewController!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        viewController.myVariable = 10


}
```

View Controller

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, SKSceneDelegate {

    var scene: GameScene!

var myVariable: Int

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        skView.presentScene(scene)
        scene.viewController = self
        }
```

Comment: Is this code from another project of yours? I am confused on the purpose of viewController.myVariable = 10

Comment: Yes, that' from a project of mine. The purpose is just to show how you access a variable on the VC from the skscene.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. I ended passing the UIViewController into the initializer of the SKScene

Comment: make sure you set one of them as weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

It says it that

```
…skView.presentScene(scene)
        scene.viewController = self
```

SKView can’t work and neither will skView. PresentScene can’t be used on type SKView